# Chromecast not available for testing

Tags: google-cast

I added my Chromecast device on the "Google Cast SDK Developer Console" and it's showing as "Ready For Testing" on the console. Unfortunately, my device isn't showing as available when I'm launching from an un-published app.

Additionally, the remote debugger isn't loading at http://[ip]:9222

Any clue on how to resolve? I've tried removing/adding the device again and rebooting it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have entered the correct serial number (take a photo and enlarge it since it is easy to read it incorrectly) in the dev console. Also reboot your chromecast to read the config again. If it still doesn't work, contact our [help](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1) center for further assistance.